# App exits on back button click in android qtquick

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am developing an app which will run firstly on Android. However, I have an issue with back button: each time it is tapped the application quits. I don't want this behaviour. I have checked a lot of approaches and I've tried to implement some code but nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
Item {
    id: student_home_page;
    focus: true

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Keys.onReleased: {
        console.log("TEST for Back ");
        if (event.key == Qt.Key_Back) {
            console.log("BAck Button HAndled");
            event.accepted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click back button after reaching this page, it does not print anything on console as it is not going inside

I only get this message on console of Qt Creator:

> /uniActivity(15431): onStop
>       I/AndroidRuntime(15431): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.

Any idea why it is not handling this key event or not any at all inside?

Comment: The safest QML-way of solving the issue is given in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30052804/2538363).

Answer (score 3):

You should handle the back button inside the `StackView` itself, not a child page, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092532/back-key-navigation-doesnt-work-even-though-focus-is-set-to-true)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be useful for you. Try to override the activity onBackPressed() method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do something or call finish()
}
```

Comment: it changes nothing ..still the issue...:(